# How to structure efficiently data in f#

Tags: f#

I am quite new with F# and still trying to decide what the best structure for my financial (back testing) program should be.
As data are immutable, I am thinking that "heavy"/all-in-one structures might not be ideal.

Here is what I try to achieve:

1. A backtesting engine which creates a strategy every business days.
   The strategy consists of a few instruments with a seq/list of trades
   (trading date / quantity / price)
2. I then run calculation (value, risks etc) daily on all those positions for each portfolio. I also add trades to each instruments each day as I adjust the position.

How I first constructed it:

- List or seq of dates: [D1 .. Dn]
- List or seq of Portfolio Pi [P1 .. Pn] (with several instruments). Each portoflio will start its life at a different Di
- For each portfolio, I will have some daily trades on the instrusments
  when I compute value, profit and losses, risks ...

What I have used for now (very simplified):

```
type Instrument1 = {
  some specifications
}

type Instrument2 = {
  some specifications
}

type Instrument = 
  | Inst1 of Instrument1
  | Inst2 of Instrument2


type Trade = {
  Dt ; DateTime
  Qty : float
  Price : float }

type Portfolio = {
   InitDate : DateTime // one of the Di above
   Inst : Instruments
   Trades : Trade seq }

type BackTesting =
   Dates : DateTime seq
   Port : Portfolio seq }
```

And then I create a seq (Dates) of seq (Portfolio) of seq (Instrument) showing let's say P&L.

However, for each portfolio Pi I am iterating on all dates to check if I need to adjust the portfolio and then add a trade to the trade list, it means that every day, for every portfolio, for every instrument, I am creating a new BackTesting (non mutable). I believe this way of reasoning is way more OOP than FP but I am a bit lost on proper patterns to use (the F# books I have used are not very clear on the data structure that works best for FP - or I did not really understand them).

I might not be very clear but if anyone has a direction into which I should look at (or any useful documentation/support on the issue), please do not hesitate. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: In case you're not aware, even though lists are immutable, they are not copied in full each time you add or remove an item from the front. Their immutability allows them to use structural sharing: If you add an one item to the front of an existing list, you are only storing that one item and a reference to the original list to get the remaining items.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox while that's true they are also slow as molasses :-) Of course everything needs to be benchmarked but the go to structures would be `seq` if memory is a concern and there is need for laziness, and `array` if processing speed. Maps/Dictionaries can be used for fast look-up.

Comment: I think reading Scott W could be a good way to learn on idiomatic way to model in F#. He has some great and very readable blogs and presentations for example:  https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/designing-with-types.html . When it comes to efficiency this comes down to your usecase. Sometimes you need to go barebones and model data columnar. Sometimes you can afford nice idioms.

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting with F#, my suggestion to you is to not worry too much about programming in a purely functional way. If you come from an imperative style of programming it may be too much of a change and you may be discouraged. The shift from imperative style to functional style takes time and it's gradual.

The good thing is F# lets you be imperative too!
So program like you would in other languages:

- Use global `mutable` variables when it best suits you.
- Use `for` and `while`
- Did you know that array elements are mutable?

As you progress you will learn the functional way, some things are really easy to use
right away:

- Definitely use `option`, never `null`
- Try using `map`, `filter`, `choose` over `list`, `array` or `seq`.

In time you will naturally gravitate more towards the functional style but you don't have to jump all at once. One of the best resources to get started is https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ its full of very good articles, slides, videos conveyed in a clear way.

Good luck!